# Good PHP format to be read by jquerymobile script

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am want to know which format I should return from my PHP script so that this jquery script can be usable :

```
 success: function (resp) {
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
    if (resp.success === true) {

    } else {

     }
}
```

Actually I did this on my php script :

```
$ar = array('success' => true);
echo json_encode($ar);
```

Which returns me this : `{"success":true}`

But I can't get it working on the ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX request expects JSON (if `dataType: 'json'`) but you do not return JSON via your PHP output because the default content type is `text/html` and not `application/json`. Add the appropriate `Content-Type` header before `echo`'ing your JSON output.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('something' => 'else'));
```

Comment: This wors! Thanks @Tom, my issue was the returned format of the php script!

Comment: @pollux1er I am glad I was able to help :)